# Data mining termin "fledged"?

Tags: text, nlp, data-mining, text-parsing, turing-machines

Please tell what is termin "full fledged KI"? As i understand it is part of data mining for text analyzing. Am i right? Some interesting and useful links will be fine!

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can I get it in context?  A lot of NLP people are linguists, and thus use a totally different set of terms.  I'm pretty well convinced that this is proof of NLP's AI-Complete nature, in and of itself.

Comment: @Jake thank you! I took this termin from answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286550/extract-text-from-external-url/4286858#4286858

Comment: In the future, just ask for clarification on the original answer. This doesn't need to be a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "full fledged", he likely means "fully fledged", defined as

1. developed or matured to the fullest degree
2. of full rank or status

source: thefreedictionary.com

Not sure about KI, but possibly it means:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_integration

Comment: By "KI" I actually meant "AI" as in "Artificial Intelligence". "KI" is just the german word for it ("Künstliche Intelligenz"), which I used mistakenly.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it is a typo of AI or a near-synonym, given the context, and my knowledge of the topic.